# Why isn't the LostFocus event occurring?

Tags: vb.net, focus

With a listbox visible, I have clicked on the windows form hoping to use the listbox.lostfocus event to let me hide the listbox - but the event does not occur.  I suppose I can use the form.click event to hide the listbox, but how would I get the form to accept focus?

Comment: What is the purpose of the listbox?  You may be using the wrong control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Form does *not* want to receive the focus.  It was designed to be a container control, it makes sure that one of its child controls always gets the focus.  It is technically possible to whack it over the head and make it lose that behavior:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, false);
    }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
        this.Focus();
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

This is however a bad idea.  A Form doesn't have any way to indicate that it has the focus, you'll also have to override OnPaint() to do something like draw a focus rectangle.  If you don't then the user completely loses track of where the focus is located.  Then there's the considerable inconvenience that nothing interesting can happen when the user uses the keyboard, a form doesn't have a use for it.

Don't do this.  If you want to make a control disappear then add a menu item, toolbar button or a normal button to your UI.  Something the user can click on.

Comment: "this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, false);" has no effect when i tried it, just "this.Focus();" onClick do it

Answer (score 0):

the LostFocus event work when the focus move to another control like textbox,... or when the form all of it lost the focus you can use click event for the form to detect taht